# Heap corruption when deleting HBITMAP object

Tags: c++, object, mfc, heap-corruption

I wrote this piece of code to print a bitmap to my dialog box in an MFC program (C++ in Visual Studio 2010):

```
//Loop start
{
    //...
    //some prep stuff
    //...

    HBITMAP hBmp = myObv->GetBMP();
    CBitmap bmp;
    bmp.Attach(hBmp);
    CClientDC dc(this);
    CDC bmDC;
    bmDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
    CBitmap *pOldbmp = bmDC.SelectObject(&bmp);
    BITMAP  bi;
    bmp.GetBitmap(&bi);
    dc.BitBlt(384,26,bi.bmWidth/3,bi.bmHeight,&bmDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);
    bmDC.SelectObject(pOldbmp);

}
```

This works fine except that as I continuously run the program and more bitmaps get drawn, the program very rapidly (linerally) begins to chew away at my available memory:

[image: memory]

Obviously the rapid drop is me closing the program.

***But when I try to delete some of the objects to try to stop the memory leak, my program crashes.***

Ex: If I do

```
    delete hBmp;
```

I get the error:

[image: error]

or if I delete pOldbmp, I get the error:

[image: error]

If I declare these objects outside the loop and just keep reusing them, I get fatal abort errors:

[image: fatal]

What's the deal??

Why can't I delete these objects?

Comment: don't `delete hBmp` - you didn't get it from `new` did you? Use `DeleteOBject(hBmp)` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DeleteObject(hBmp)` instead.

This is happening because you're attempting to `delete hBmp` while still having selected it using `SelectObject()`.

Comment: This worked for all of them except for BITMAP bi.  Any other way to delete that one?

Comment: `bi` is a stack object, it will be deleted automatically when your function returns. @xcdemon05

Comment: Could that be the source of the memory leak since this is all happening in an infinite loop?  Would that mean that it's never getting deleted?

Comment: wait no, when the loop finishes, the stack object `BITMAP bi` is deleted anyway.

Comment: So for clarification each run through the loop will delete bi?

Comment: Yes it will.. because `bi` goes out of scope, each time the loop iterates, and comes back in with next iteration.